# FMOD : How to get a free channel?

Tags: c#, fmod

I am new to FMOD. Honestly it's quite an easy library to use, but I can't seem to find a method to get a free channel aside from creating a sound, which I don't want since I want to be able to allocate a channel to my object without having to create a sound immediately.

Do you know how I there is a way I could get any free sound channel ? (and if possible to choose between hardware and software channel)

Thanks in advance for your advices :)

Comment: Nobody can help me there ? :(

Answer (score 0):

```
system->createSound("example.mp3", FMOD_HARDWARE, 0, &Sound);
```

FMOD_HARDWARE - hardware support or use FMOD_SOFTWARE

```
system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, Sound, false, &Channel);
```

FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE - automatically use free channel. or you can use FMOD_CHANNEL_REUSE